# How get access to array inside object?

Tags: php, arrays

I have connected to SOAP by WSLD and get an object where lives an array with data.

Here is results of **print_r**:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetCommonInfoMkdResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Municipals] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [MunInion] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [MKD] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [TotalCount] => 473
                                            [TotalArea] => 1419701.74
                                        )

                                    [Inhabitants] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [TotalCount] => 45919
                                        )

                                    ...

                                    [Name] => город-курорт Ессентуки
                                )
so on...
```

Same object by **var_dump**

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'GetCommonInfoMkdResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'Municipals' => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'MunInion' => 
            array (size=35)
              ...
      public 'Result' => 
        object(stdClass)[358]
```

How i can get access to **MunInion** array?

Comment: And what have you done so far? =)

Comment: `$obj->GetCommonInfoMkdResult->Municipals->MunInion[0]->MKD->..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it with:

```
$obj = YOUR_WSDL_OBJECT;
$MunicipalsArray = $obj->GetCommonInfoMkdResult->Municipals->MunInion;
```

Or a certain field:

```
$TotalCount = $obj->GetCommonInfoMkdResult->Municipals->MunInion[0]->MKD->TotalCount;
```